# How to retrieve a value from a Store field within a Playa relationship with a Matrix Cell?

Tags: expresso-store, matrix, playa, relationships

I can't quite get my head around this one but I'm using Expresso Store, Playa, and Matrix. The parent entry has a Matrix field with a Playa relationship field in one of the cells. This links to a product which is of the Store field type. I need to retrieve the price of that product in the other channel. How?

To clarify, I have a '*Lists*' channel and a '*Gifts*' channel. The *Gifts* channel stores the product info using the Store field. The *Lists* channel is the parent and makes the relationship. The product is related (by title of the product) in a Matrix field in the parent. I can extract the title of the product successfully like this:

```
{product_list} {!-- Matrix field of the parent --}
    {product}  {!-- Matrix cell of the above field --}
        {title} {!-- Title of the product successfully retrieved --}
    {/product}
{/product_list}
```

The above works. The following doesn't work but it's the kind of thing that I want to be able to do but don't know how with this level of nesting or retrieval:

```
{product_list} {!-- Matrix field of the parent --}
    {product}  {!-- Matrix cell of the above field --}
        {title} {!-- Title of the product successfully retrieved --}
        {product_info} {!-- Store field of the related product in Gifts channel --}
            {regular_price} {!-- Price field within the Store field --}
        {/product_info}
    {/product}
{/product_list}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this if you are just wanting to have price you would want do something along the following (as referenced [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#product_tag_variables))

> Most variables can also be used outside of the product form, inside a
>   standard {exp:channel:entries} loop. For example, if your Store
>   products custom field is named “product_details”, then the price is
>   also accessible as: `{product_details:price}`

```
{product_list} {!-- Matrix field of the parent --}
    {product}  {!-- Matrix cell of the above field --}
        {title} {!-- Title of the product successfully retrieved --}
        {product_info:price} {!-- This is the format of custom_field_name:value_to_retieve --}
        {product_info:regular_price}
        {product_info:sale_price}
    {/product}
{/product_list}
```

If you are wanting to add the item to the cart you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
{product_list} {!-- Matrix field of the parent --}
    {product}  {!-- Matrix cell of the above field --}
        {title} {!-- Title of the product successfully retrieved --}
        {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"} {!-- Store field of the related product in Gifts channel --}
            {regular_price} {!-- Price field within the Store field --}
Other fields here like quantity, modifiers, and a submit button
        {/exp:store:product}
    {/product}
{/product_list}
```

Comment: Dude, you rock HARD! That's exactly what I needed and works like a charm for both child info retrieval (product details from Gifts channel) and in terms of adding to the cart (which was the other bit I needed and was going to ask next). Nicely anticipated. I'd say it's worth an extra vote for the slightly unnerving but not unwelcome foresight into my next question too. :) Thanks for the quick response too. Legend!

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you. I edited my my answer to actually be properly formatted code block.